# WCF Web.config - The configuration section 'system.webserver' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, web-config, asp.net-4.0

I'm on Visual Studio 2010 and Target is 4.0. What's wrong with this web.config?

I'm getting 500 error on local web server: 
The configuration section 'system.webserver' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetframework="4.0">
            <authentication mode="None">
            </authentication>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.webserver>
        <modules runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webserver>
    <system.servicemodel>
        <servicehostingenvironment aspnetcompatibilityenabled="true">
            <standardendpoints>
                <webscriptendpoint>
                    <standardendpoint crossdomainscriptaccessenabled="true">
                    </standardendpoint>
                </webscriptendpoint>
            </standardendpoints>
        </servicehostingenvironment>
    </system.servicemodel>
</configuration>
```

It's giving me these warnings in VS:

Warning 1   p:\jcp\WCF1\WCF1\Service1.svc: ASP.NET runtime error: Unrecognized configuration section system.webserver. (p:\jcp\WCF1\WCF1\web.config line 9) p:\jcp\WCF1\WCF1\Service1.svc   1   1   WCF1

Warning 2   The 'targetframework' attribute is not allowed. p:\jcp\WCF1\WCF1\Web.config 4   29  WCF1

Warning 3   The element 'compilation' has invalid child element 'authentication'. List of possible elements expected: 'assemblies, buildProviders, codeSubDirectories, expressionBuilders, folderLevelBuildProviders'.  p:\jcp\WCF1\WCF1\Web.config 5   5   WCF1

I've set my project to use local IIS and created on virtual. My client is Windows 7 pro with iis7 and the apppool for the folder is set to 4.0.  Do I need .net 3.5 installed on the client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I think might account for the errors you're seeing:

1. Web.configs are case senstive.  You'll need to camel-case your text (e.g. `system.webServer`, `targetFramework`, `system.serviceModel`.)
2. `system.web.authentication` is a peer of `system.web.compilation`, and not a child of it.

Comment: Thanks. Tried these and did not help. Some other post suggesting I need to make manual changes to system.config files in .NET versions.  Looking like another MS reboot or rebuild if I can't figure this out. Also, it appears I'm on IIS 7.5

Comment: I'm getting this now: The configuration section 'System.ServiceModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Comment: XML is picky.  `System.ServiceModel` won't work, but `system.serviceModel` should.  I should have been more specific when I mentioned camel-casing:  it has to be of the variety in which you leave the first word lower-cased, but capitalize the others.

Comment: Wow. I grabbed that code from code project and it was all in lower case. It seems the service is up, though having my problems consuming it now with JQuery and the provided scripts.  Thanks for your time on this!

Answer (score 1):

i too had this for a spelling mistake, took me a couple of times to see that i missed the 'n' in environment, worth to put the entire file in a VS proj to let it test it